# Can a WPA key be shorter than 8 characters?

Tags: wifi, wpa

I was helping a person with his computer today, and he was convinced that his router's WPA key was 7 characters (with some brand of consumer router). He has been able to connect with this on a number of computers, but when stepping him through it with Ubuntu we found that Network Manager imposes a strict limit of 8 or more characters.

Before I fire off a bug report, I would like to know: is that 8 or more character limit a hard, technical limit (and the guy on the phone just crazy), or is it indeed possible to have a WPA key with 7 characters?

Comment: Should be migrated to SU.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but it is almost certainly a bad idea.  A password that small would be easy to guess through brute force.  You may want to try to strongly encourage him to use something much longer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WPA Pre-shared key (PSK) mode, defined in [IEEE 802.11i-2004](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11i-2004.pdf), uses PBKDF2 as described in [PKCS #5](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt).  While PBKDF2 has no minimum length, the IEEE standard states in *H.4 Suggested pass-phrase-to-PSK mapping* (which includes a discussion of security considerations):

> A pass-phrase is a sequence of between
>   8 and 63 ASCII-encoded characters. The
>   limit of 63 comes from the desire to
>   distinguish between a pass-phrase and
>   a PSK displayed as 64 hexadecimal
>   characters.

**UPDATE:** A thought occurs -- note that this is based on ASCII characters.  Perhaps your 7-character WPA PSK has trailing whitespace!

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's probably what I should have asked the guy to do. Next time I come across this, I will try that :)

Looking at the IEEE's spec, they only mention the minimum 8 characters thing once. In H.4.2 reference implementation, it isn't enforced and it doesn't look like the output would be wrongly influenced.

Hm… Still a little lost, but I'm definitely less lost.